# Can Amazon Connect retrieve the error message from a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

Is it possible to capture a thrown error message from a lambda function in Amazon Connect?

Example lambda throwing an error:

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    throw new Error('some error message')
};
```

I would like to use the error message in a voice prompt, without catching the error.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Of course, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

> When a synchronous invocation returns an error, Amazon Connect retries up to 3 times, for a maximum of 8 seconds. At that point, the flow will progress down the Error branch.

An Error branch, is this what you want? see [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just return it in the response and then access via contact attribute.